# Find My Phone email notifications

Tags: email

One of the purposes I use Find My Phone is to keep track (when needed) of my children. Now they are receiving email messages that I am using the feature - which defeats the purpose of why I use it. Is there a way to turn off the email notifications?

Comment: Nope...it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reluctant to suggest this without knowing more about your situation, but taking your question at face value, you might want to look into Apple's [Find My Friends](https://www.apple.com/apps/find-my-friends/) app.

It has various settings that control who can see a phone's location and for how long they can see it. And with the Restriction settings within iOS you can set various settings and lock them down.

There are various articles online about parents using Find My Friends in a positive way with their children. For example:

http://www.allprodad.com/articles/dads-and-teenagers/find-my-friends/

http://dotcomplicated.co/content/2013/05/location-tracking-app/

Answer (score 0):

The way i am currently disabling this is by going to my children's email accounts and setting up rules to automatically delete this email when it comes in, its not perfect, but it will work for now.

Answer (score 0):

You may not turn that off, but you can switch iPhone Mail's new mail alert sound on or off:

```
Tap Settings on the Home screen.
Now tap Sounds.
Set New Mail to ON or OFF.
```